# Doesn’t Google support Schema.org’s AggregateRating at the moment?

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

A rich snippet example from Schema.org http://schema.org/AggregateRating:

```
<html>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <img itemprop="image" src="dell-30in-lcd.jpg" />
  <span itemprop="name">Dell UltraSharp 30" LCD Monitor</span>

  <div itemprop="aggregateRating"
    itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">87</span>
    out of <span itemprop="bestRating">100</span>
    based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">24</span> user ratings
  </div>

</div>
</html>
```

But http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets won't show a preview.

So, the following words from http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146645 are just lies?

> New! schema.org lets you mark up a much wider range of item types on
>   your pages, using a vocabulary that Google, Microsoft, and Yahoo! can
>   all understand. Find out more. (Google still supports your existing
>   rich snippets markup, though.)

Comment: I and many others have working rich snippets including aggregate reviews. Don't forget the preview tool is beta and Google is not obliged to use your markup. First guess is a div in an html tag is way invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working absolutely fine.

Google is not obliged to show you preview every time, and here it shows an error when I inserted your give example from schema.org:

```
The following errors were found during preview generation:
This page does not contain authorship or rich snippet markup.
```

I have done it in my website's news pieces and it shows [fine](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://bengalimovies.org/news/celebs-gathered-tabe-tai-hok-s-music-release-10726).